# How to follow the output of a command in a terminal window

Tags: neovim, scrolling, terminal-buffer

I recently decided to give a try at neovim and one thing is bothering me:

I use a terminal window to run my code watcher i.e. a never ending command which outputs new lines each time I write a buffer.

If I put my cursor on this window and use `G` the window will keep track of the output and I will always see the last lines of the output *as long as I don't switch of window*.

If I change of tab or of window, the window containing the terminal buffer stops scrolling and I have to go back to this window and use `G` again to see the end of my output.

If feel like I'm missing something but I wasn't able to find a solution to this problem. I guess I could have an autocommand on `TabEnter` and for example which would find a terminal buffer in the new tab and use `norm! G` in it but that feel kind of overkill (plus that wouldn't solve the problem if I have two split buffer and I work on the one next to the terminal buffer). Is there a simple solution to this problem?

**EDIT** Here are the steps to reproduce my issue:

Create a file and continuously write in it from the shell:

- `touch foo`
- `while; do; echo 'a' >> foo; sleep 1; done`

Start neovim without any config:

- `nvim -u NONE -U NONE`

In neovim:

- `:term tail -f foo` To open a terminal with a continuous output
- Go to insert mode and add an empty line to follow the output then go to normal mode and `G`
- `:tabnew`

Wait a few seconds

When going to the first tab, the empty line should have changed of place, for me it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** The problem was actually a bug in neovim fixed by the commit [47b7b471fa](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commit/47b7b471fa0f33550f886dc93976ded97f602292) which is now merged in master.

---

So after [asking the Neovim issue tracker](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/10696) it turns out this is the current "expected" behavior of the code:

In [terminal.c](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/f5d1e0e7b1837e8b76f1561167543c90a9942a7a/src/nvim/terminal.c#L1309) the function `adjust_topline()` iterates over `FOR_ALL_WINDOWS_IN_TAB`, changing that to iterate over `FOR_ALL_TAB_WINDOWS` fixes my issue.

I'm not sure of the implications regarding the performances of this change, but if the neovim community agrees I'll create a PR.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this oneliner (from this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/417939/145897), tnx [eli](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/161003/eli))

```
:set autoread | au CursorHold * checktime | call feedkeys("G")
```

Explanation:

- `autoread`: reads the file when changed from the outside
- `CursorHold * checktime`: when the cursor isn't moved by the user for the time specified in `updatetime` (which is 4000 miliseconds by default) `checktime` is executed, which checks for changes from outside the file
- `call feedkeys("G")`: the cursor is moved to the end of file

To stop the scrolling when using `call feedkeys("G")`, execute `:set noautoread` - now vim will tell, that the file was change ans ask if one wants to read the changes or not)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's not exactly what I want: If I reuse it as you posted it, it has a lot of side effects: `autoread` is set for every buffer and the autocommand too so every buffer will constantly jump to the end which is pretty annoying. So I tried to adapt it so that only term buffers are affected: `autocmd CursorHold term//* checktime | call feedkeys("G")` but then it works when I change of window but if I do `tabnext` (and `tabprev` again) the terminal buffer isn't updated anymore (I'm not sure why)

Comment: @statox you a right. Seems weird, but switching tab freezes autoscroll in term window. I tried `:au FocusGained,BufEnter,TabEnter,CursorHold,CursorHoldI term//* if mode()!='c' | checktime | call feedkeys("G") | endif` , but did not help